# How do I repeat the program?

Tags: python

I was wondering how to reset this program, and I need help. I have been looking everywhere for an answer, but I can't find a program that works.  Can someone please help me?

```
print("Answer These MATH Questions")
def program():
    math = int(input("What Is 8 x 4: ")) 
    if math == ("32"):
        print("You Got The Question Correct") 
    else:
        print("Sorry You Got The Question Wrong Try Again") 
        program()
        return
```

Comment: Why do you convert the input to an integer if you are going to compare it to a string?

Comment: sorry im new to programing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [while](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WhileLoop) like example. Don't use int for input - maybe it will not number:

```
while 1:
    math = input("What Is 8 x 4: ")
    if not math.isdigit():
        print("It's not number")

    elif math == "32":
        print("You Got The Question Correct")
        break

    else:
        print("Sorry You Got The Question Wrong Try Again")
```

Comment: You're using `elif` and still checking the same condition again? Why?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3, first version has just if, i forgot fix it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

change `if math == ("32"):` to `if math == 32:`