# Python making a number guessing game

Tags: python

The code I have:

```
import random

guessesTaken = 0

print('Hello! What is your name?')
myName = input()

number = random.randint(1, 20)
print('Well, ' + myName + ', I am thinking of a number between 1 and 20.')

while guessesTaken < 5:
     print('Take a guess.')

     guess = input()
     guess = int(guess)
     guessesTaken = guessesTaken + 1
     guessesTaken = print('Thats a guess gone.')


     if guess < number:
         print('Your guess is too low.') 


     if guess > number:
         print('Your guess is too high.')

     if guess == number:
          print('You won at life!')
          break

     if guess == number:
        print('idk, ' + myName + '! You guessed my number in ' + guessesTaken + ' guesses!')
print('Again? Again.')
```

Need help with:

1.This error - Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "\\wbs-fs01\2013$\13CDyke\Guessing game.py", line 12, in <module>
    while guessesTaken < 5:
TypeError: unorderable types: NoneType() < int()
```

2.Need to fix it and display how many guesses you got the answer in.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this line:

```
guessesTaken = print('Thats a guess gone.')
```

`print` returns `None`, so that's the value your variable gets. Remove the assignment and it'll work:

```
print('Thats a guess gone.')
```

Comment: Thanks that worked, also could you help me make it repeat upon inputting something like "Yes" or "No"

Comment: @OBCCraig Stack Overflow has already helped a trillion other people do that. These two for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12557376/python-repeat-program-while-true http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36273970/how-do-i-repeat-the-program/36274003